# handling Group notification in react native firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am trying to handle group notifications in my react native project using firebase cloud messaging. notifications come correctly in foreground/background and when app is killed but i have problem to group my notifications. i used groupChannel as the documentation said but when notifications have been sent to device , the newer one replaces the old one.
here is what i send through postman:
{
    "to": "my-token",
    "priority":"high",
    "data": {
        "title": "my title",
        "body": "Lorem",
        "remote": true,
        "sound":"default",
        "priority":"high",
        "groupId":"Group2",
        "tag":"GroupTag"
    }

}

here are my codes:

```
   this.notificationListener =  firebase.messaging().onMessage(async message=>{
  console.log(message,'foreground')

    const {body,title,sound,groupId,tag} = message.data;
    const GroupChannelId = new firebase.notifications.Android.ChannelGroup(
      groupId,
      'Group')
      firebase.notifications().android.createChannelGroup(GroupChannelId);
      const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
      .setTitle(title)
      .setBody(body)
      .setData(message.data)
      .setNotificationId(groupId)
      .android.setGroup(groupId)
      .android.setBigText(body)
      .android.setVibrate([600,300,200,300,500])
      .android.setAutoCancel(true)
      .android.setChannelId(groupId)
      .android.setGroupAlertBehaviour(firebase.notifications.Android.GroupAlert.Children)
      .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);

const date = new Date();
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 1);
firebase.notifications().scheduleNotification(localNotification,{
  fireDate:date.getTime()
})

  firebase.notifications().displayNotification(localNotification);

})
```